# How do enable the Tomcat Web Application Manager in Jelastic?

Tags: tomcat, jelastic

I've set up a Tomcat 9 application server on Jelastic and I'm having trouble setting up access the tomcat manager application. I tried following [these instructions](https://geekflare.com/tomcat-login-problem/) but there inside the webapps directory there is no manager subdirectory. Is the Tomcat manager application deliberately disabled in Jelastic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [download](https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.17/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.17.zip) the matching version of tomcat, extract the `webapps/manager` folder from the .zip file and then upload the `manager` into the remote webapps folder (just deploy it as any other normal web application). Afterwards follow the instructions you already found to configure the manager.

Comment: That worked. Created .war file by running `jar -cvf manager.war *` in the webapps/manager directory of the unzipped download then uploaded manager.war to Tomcat via Jelastic web interface.